# How long can I keep sauteed onions in the fridge?

Tags: storage-lifetime, onions, sauteing

I'm a working mom, so I'm always trying to find ways to cut down on cooking time. My newest trick is to saute a huge batch of onions and keep it in a container in the fridge, so that I can skip the onion-frying step of recipes. How long can I store sauteed onions in the fridge? I want to freeze any onions that I won't be able to use within a safe period of time, so I'm wondering how long that is.

Comment: related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/19557/8291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stilltasty.com](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17825) gives you 3-5 days on cooked onions in the fridge - after that, tightly wrapped and airtight into the freezer.