# Cooked or caramalized onions in the refrigerator

Tags: onions

How long can I store caramalized onions in the refrigerator?

Comment: related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18658/8291

Answer (score 1):

For cooked onions, you can find one answer here: http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/17825

- 3-5 days in the refrigerator.
- refrigerate withing 2 hours of cooking.
- refrigerate in covered container or wrap tightly with heavy-duty aluminum foil or plastic wrap.

Comment: I agree compeltely with Glauber Rocha; @Shirley, although you asked about storing in the refrigerator, it is worth noting also that caramelized onions store very well in the freezer, up to six months.